# How to reduce memory usage of a docusaurus build (v2)?

Tags: javascript, webpack, build, bitbucket-pipelines, docusaurus

I'm using docusaurus v2.0.0-alpha.39 to generate documentation, and bitbucket pipelines to build everything and push it to AWS.

The problem is I'm hitting `Container 'Build' exceeded memory limit.` when executing the `yarn build`command.

In `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`, I've already bump up the memory at the maximum I can (7680mb for build and 512mb for docker):

```
deploy: &deploy
    size: 2x
    name: Deploy
    caches:
      - node
    script:
      - yarn
      - yarn build
```

I've also tried to limit node memory usage by setting `--max-old-space-size=7168` in various ways :

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=7168 node node_modules/@docusaurus/core/bin/docusaurus build"
  }
}
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=7168 node node_modules/@docusaurus/core/bin/docusaurus build"
  }
}
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node --max-old-space-size=7168 node_modules/@docusaurus/core/bin/docusaurus build"
  }
}
```

But no matter what i put as max variable, my node process goes up and use up to 14GB of memory !
And if I put a "small" --max-old-space-size, i get :

`FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

I have pretty huge docs(6,3 MB and 1.493 items per version) i have to admit but I can't even version them using docusaurus, each version add 4/5GB of memory usage...

Do you have any idea of potential solutions for this ?

Comment: How big is your docs size ? Quantity wise and size wise. Its hard to tell anything without looking at the repo and we need more information. We have heavy dependencies on Webpack & its ecosystem and its hard to track if the leak is due to Docusaurus code itself or the dependency. For example, terser (used by millions of repo) recently had a memory leak that causes heap out of memory for a lot of repo.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! 
6,3 MB and 1.493 items per versions, and I works only with 1 version on Bitbucket and 2 versions when build on local